Is it the case that $\cos(\arccos(z))=z \iff z\in[-1,1]$? Is my derivation of the falsity of that statement incorrect?
I was recently told that $\cos(\arccos(z))=z \iff z\in[-1,1]$ $\tag1$
I came to a different conclusion by using the following reasoning:
Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$
Let $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ denote the principal natural log of $z$
It's well-known (and can be verified) that $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ we have $$\arccos(z)_{12}=\frac{\pi}{2}+i\operatorname{Log}(\pm\sqrt{1-z^2}+iz)$$
Thus, $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$ we have $$\cos(\arccos(z))=-\sin(i\operatorname{Log}(\pm\sqrt{1-z^2}+iz))=z$$ $\tag2$
Wolfram can confirm that the latter 2 expressions are equivalent
Given that (2) contradicts (1), I must have made an error in my reasoning at some point, but the only place where I can possibly see there being a flaw is where I used the trig identity $$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+f(z))=-\sin(f(z))$$
Is that where my mistake happened? If so, why doesn't the usual trig identity apply?

$\text{arccos}(z)$ is defined to something whose cosine is $z$. So $\text{cos}(\text{arccos}(z))=z\iff\exists x(\text{cos}(x)=z)$.
$\text{cos}(\text{arccos}(z))\iff z\in[-1,1]$ over $\mathbb R$ is true because if $z\notin[-1,1]$ then $\text{arccos}(z)$ is undefined over $\mathbb R$. However, cos is surjective over $\mathbb C$ so arccos is always defined over $\mathbb C$.
The answer depends on the domain you are considering.
